# CMD pause JavaCPL.exe

Tags: java, windows, cmd

Friends
I hope they help me, I'm doing a job and the automation is that the java control panel start through CMD and once it is closed, start executing the following CMD lines

the execution that I am doing is the following:

```
start / wait javacpl.exe
```

Nota: esto es un sistema windows 7
regards

Comment: Does this work for you?

Comment: Note that their (at least) shouldn't be a space between `/` and `wait`. Having that said, you'll need to provide more information for solving this, or if `start /wait javacpl.exe` did work for you already then.

Comment: Use `START /?` to read the documentation on using the START command. If you still have questions, post the code, including any error messages, and describe what is happening.